# cocos2d-android: how to play/pause a game state

Tags: android, ccsprite, cocos2d-android

I am new to cocos2d-android. I want to play or/and pause my game . How I fix it ? What would be the method? Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Is it possible to do using CCMenuItemToggle ? plz any idea ...

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the pause or play through this CCMenuItemImage. you can easily handle the activity.